# SQL group by functionality confusion

Tags: mysql-workbench

im new to mysql i would like to know how to use group by function efficiently to fetch the results?please provide examples with joins involved TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GROUP BY clause is used to limit an aggregate function (of which count() is only one of several) to a certain range. Without a group clause the aggregate would operate on all values in a table (further determined by a WHERE clause, if necessary). Grouping first splits the rows in a table/view into individual sets determined by group clause (all those entries belong to one group that have the same value, specified by the GROUP BY clause) and then applies the aggregate to each of them.

Example:

Assume you have a table with people, departments and income. You can now determine the sum of all income (or max, or min etc.) by running

```
select sum(income) from people;
```

Which returns a single value: the sum of all income.

For individual departments you can then group the result:

```
select department, sum(income) from people group by department;
```

This returns as many rows as there are departments and a sum of all income per department. Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html along with a list of possible aggregate functions.

Btw. Don't let people confuse you by statements like "group is mostly used with count()" which is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"group by" is usually used with count.

Consider an example table as

```
create table Country(state varchar(10),district varchar(10));
```

Now, suppose you want to find "How many districts are there in every state". I would use the query.

```
select state,count(district) from Country group by state;
```